# Chromium build failed on Ubuntu : ERROR at //build_overrides/build.gni:5:1: Unable to load "/home/chromium/src/build/config/gclient_args.gni"

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, chromium, ninja

I am trying to build Chromium on Ubuntu using these instructions
 [1] https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md

and getting below error

```sh
VirtualBox:~/chromium/src$ gn gen out/Default
ERROR at //build_overrides/build.gni:5:1: Unable to load "/home/chromium/src/build/config/gclient_args.gni".
import("//build/config/gclient_args.gni")
^---------------------------------------
See //build/toolchain/toolchain.gni:9:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build_overrides/build.gni")
^-----------------------------------
See //build/config/coverage/coverage.gni:5:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/toolchain/toolchain.gni")
^---------------------------------------
See //build/config/sanitizers/sanitizers.gni:7:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/coverage/coverage.gni")
^--------------------------------------------
See //build/config/compiler/compiler.gni:8:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/sanitizers/sanitizers.gni")
^------------------------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:11:1: whence it was imported.
import("//build/config/compiler/compiler.gni")
^--------------------------------------------
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: did you find the fix? I have the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fix by adding the missing file (I've copied from an old build) and than run:

> gclient sync --force

Than I run again the getThirdParties.js and gn args out/Default.

Comment: what is getThirdParties.js? I'm getting this error running `tools/dev/gm.py arm64.release`